Finding all the primes that verify $p+49=2x^{2}$ and $p^{2}+49=2y^{2}$
The problem is the following: find all the prime numbers $p$ such that:
$p+49=2x^{2}$ and $p^{2}+49=2y^{2}$.
My approach was based in studying two cases, the first case when $p\lt 49$ and the second one is when $p\gt 49$(since 49 isn't prime of course). Starting with the first case: we know that $p+49=2x^{2}$, so we can conclude that $p$ is an odd number, hence $p\ge 3$, which means that $\frac{p+49}{2}\ge \frac{52}{2}=26$. In other words $x^{2}\ge 26$. Also since $p\le 49$ we can state that $\frac{p+49}{2}\le 49$, in other words $x^{2}\le 49$, hence $26\le x^{2}\le 49$, meaning that $x^{2}=36$ so $$p=23$$ yet I couldn't quite approach the second case, in which $p\gt 49$, so any help is much appreciated.

You've made a good start, but here's another approach. Have $x$ and $y$ both be positive integers. Consider if $x \ge p \;\to\; 2x^2 \ge 2p^2$, then
$$p + 49 \ge 2p^2 \;\;\to\;\; 0 \ge 2p^2 - p - 49$$
The positive root of the right side is $\frac{1 + \sqrt{1 + 8(49)}}{4} \approx 5.2$, so $p$ is less than this. However, one may easily confirm $p \gt 7$, so this is never the case, which means $x \lt p$ instead. Similarly, since $p \gt 7 \;\to\; p^2 \gt 49$, we get
$$2y^2 = p^2 + 49 \lt 2p^2 \;\;\to\;\; y \lt p$$
Subtracting your first equation from the second one gives
$$p^2 - p = 2y^2 - 2x^2 \;\;\to\;\; p(p - 1) = 2(y - x)(y + x)$$
Since $p$ is an odd prime, then $p \mid y - x$ or $p \mid y + x$. For the first case, since $y \gt x$, we get
$$y - x = jp, \;\; j \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$$
This shows $y \gt jp \;\to\; y \gt p$, contradicting that $y \lt p$. Thus, we must have the second case of
$$y + x = kp, \;\; k \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$$
Since $y \lt p$ and $x \lt p$, this means $y + x \lt 2p$, so $k = 1$. Substituting $y = p - x$ into your second equation, and then also using your first one, gives
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
p^2 + 49 & = 2(p - x)^2 \\
p^2 + 49 & = 2p^2 - 4px + 2x^2 \\
p^2 + 49 & = 2p^2 - 4px + (p + 49) \\
0 & = p^2 - 4px + p \\
0 & = p(p - 4x + 1)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
Since $p \neq 0$, then $p - 4x + 1 = 0 \;\to\; p = 4x - 1$. Substituting this into your first equation results in
$$(4x - 1) + 49 = 2x^2 \;\to\; x^2 - 2x - 24 = 0 \;\to\; (x + 4)(x - 6) = 0 \;\to\; x = -4, 6$$
Since $x \gt 0$, we can exclude $x = -4$ (also, it leads to $p = -17$), so then $x = 6$. This gives $p = 4(6) - 1 = 23$ as the only solution, i.e., the one you've already determined.
